# WEB page loads only with second attempt - DNS issues

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I'm having this issue that I've never run into and wanted to ask the community for help.

I think I may be missing or overlooked something small. The issue I'm having is that I try to hit an external site, the first time usually errors out but the second time will catch. For instance if I try to hit Cisco from Chrome, the first time will error out and say "I'm not connected to the Internet" or try to return a cached version of the page. The second time will return the webpage correctly. This is happening on all internet/external sites that I'm trying to reach.

I did a trace route to see where my network is dropping the coms, and it looks like everything is getting routed back to my IP. I've never seen this so any help would be much appreciated. I've included a screen of my tracert. It does hit a 209.x.x.x once which isn't in my network...which is also confusing.

More background, I have two VMs on the same machine that do not have this issue, its only affecting the host.O, and I'm on an enterprise network and I'm the only one who is experiencing this issue

Tracert (csc2-pc is my machine)

```
Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *       <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
  7    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
  8    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
  9    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 10    32 ms    27 ms    34 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 11    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 12   147 ms    49 ms    60 ms  rd.sd.cox.net [68.x.x.x] 
 13    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 14    10 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 15    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 16    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 17   355 ms     8 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 18    <1 ms     2 ms     1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 19     8 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 20    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 21    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 22    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 23    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 24    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 25    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 26    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 27    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 28    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 29    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 
 30    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  CSC2-PC [192.168.10.130] 

 Trace complete.
```

---

```
Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CSC2-PC
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : tcp.com.br

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-E3-B5-99-FE-50
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.130(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 02, 2014 9:51:00 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, May 03, 2014 9:50:59 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.15
                                   209.242.128.100
                                   192.168.10.7
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled 

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 29:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-90-84-78-0E
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{EE0E8BEF-48B5-4435-9C3E-333CAFB29F4B}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:1841:2fe3:3f57:f57d(Preferred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1841:2fe3:3f57:f57d%12(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BBF98953-9B88-4A47-8984-BFC6AEB46F41}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

===========================================================================
Interface List
32...78 e3 b5 80 fe 50 ......Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
27...00 ff 90 90 78 0e ......Juniper Network Connect Virtual Adapter
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.10.1   192.168.10.130     20
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
 192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.10.130    276
192.168.10.130  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.130    276
192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.130    276
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.10.130    276
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.130    276
==========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
12     58 ::/0                     On-link
1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
12     58 2001::/32                On-link
12    306 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:1841:2fe3:3f57:f57d/128
                                On-link
12    306 fe80::/64                On-link
12    306 fe80::1841:2fe3:3f57:f57d/128
                                On-link
1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
12    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None
```

Comment: Can you post your `ipconfig /all` and `route print -4`?

Comment: What device is on 10.7 and 10.15?

Comment: .15 is the domain controller and .7 is server. not super sure why its on list as a DNS. looking for the drawings

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think your right and that is the next logical next step. I originally thought it might of been a routing/configuration issue because I use multiple VPN's daily. Thanks again for everyone that helped out and commented

Comment: So i figured it out. It was the wrong settings on the DHCP/Firewall, one of the circuits was issuing the wrong the wrong DNS servers.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

[From the comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/597751/web-page-loads-only-with-second-attempt-dns-issues#comment706784_597751)

> So i figured it out. It was the wrong settings on the DHCP/Firewall, one of the circuits was issuing the wrong the wrong DNS servers. Thanks everybody –  MannyFresh May 2 at 22:42